# Is it possible to get syntax highlighting and other editor services for html template literals in Svelte?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, svelte, syntax-highlighting, template-literals

I [wrote code](https://github.com/yairchu/soul-arithmetic/blob/01030c1af86f122ceef11d7ab6ba2a2da111c3fa/src/routes/%2Bpage.svelte#L44) that looks like:

```
<script lang="ts">
    ...
        {
            content: `
                <p>
                    Some content
                </p>
            `,
            ...
        },
    ...
</script>

...
{@html item.content}
...
```

I am using VS code with the Svelte extensions and I would like to get auto-formatting, synax highlighting, and other IDE services in the template literal above. I tried various VS code extensions and code modifications (like adding `/* html */` before the literal) but couldn't get a working setup.

Does anyone have a functional setup for this? What do I need to do to make it work?

Update: [H.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77065900/40916) referred to an extension that solves the syntax highlighting part . I would still very much like auto-formatting as well :)

Answer (score 4):

[`es6-string-html`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tobermory.es6-string-html) can add syntax highlighting via `/*html*/`, no formatting.

But you really should just *not* do this, create a separate component instead.

Using `@html` is also quite dangerous as soon as any unknown or user-provided data is to be used.

Comment: Alternatively put your HTML into a separate `.html` file and read it from this inline to the code if you really want to have long static HTML snippets.

Comment: Thanks! I know well that @html is not for user provided data. And as you can see in my linked code that it is not user provided.
For more context after you make a guess in https://soul-arithmetic.pages.dev it is the explanation of the answer, it is provided by the author of the game (me), not by users.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa my snippets aren't long, and I prefer to put them next to the structured data they are related to. Specifically, those are the details revealed once you make a guess at https://soul-arithmetic.pages.dev